# Separating infrequently accessed fields from a table

Tags: mysql, database-schema

I'm currently creating a site with basic user signup and have all of the user data in one table called 'users'. Eleven of the fields such as username, role etc may be required by that user while they are logged in or by the script when displaying their details. While nine of the fields such as password, email, ip etc will only ever be accessed by the user when they login. If the database is expected to handle 100,000 to 1,000,000 users should I split the login related fields into a table called 'users_login' to reduce the size of the main 'users' table?

I know there are many variables involved and the best approach is to test both versions but before I did that I'm asking for advice on if I shouldn't attempt this for some reason. Thanks

Comment: It depends......-> "I know there are many variables involved"

Comment: show us the output of "show create table users"  Separating infrequently accessed fields can be helpfull with query caching but still your query cache will be invalidated if an new user is added. So it depends.. still 100000 or 1000000 records is still an low number off records if you index correctly..

Comment: Some databases have the ability to split the columns of a table into separate units for physical storage. That lets you get the performance benefits of separating out infrequently accessed fields without having to complicate your data model. I am not a MySQL expert, but i couldn't find any way to get MySQL to do this. Can it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach, which does not require splitting the table, would be to create a *covering index*. A covering index for some query is one where the index entry itself contains all the columns needed to execute the query, meaning that execution does not need to read from the table itself. For example, for a query like `select role from user where username = ?`, then an index on (username, role) would be covering.

In your case, the covering index would on the eleven columns that may be "required by that user while they are logged in or by the script when displaying their details". You would need to put the column used as the key for the lookup (user ID or username or whatever) at the start, so the index would be on something like (username, role, and, nine, other, columns, used, frequently, while, logged, in).

Here's an example of the database team at Wikipedia using this technique to get a ~10x speedup in a very similar situation: [Where covering indexes rock](http://dom.as/2007/01/26/mysql-covering-index-performance/).